# how to call CLLocation delegate only after moving 100m

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, cllocationmanager

I am working with CLLocation in my app. What I want to do is if I move a distance of 100m then I want to call a server api but if it is less than 100m or the phone is stationary no server call to be made.

What I am currently doing is

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
_locationManager.distanceFilter = 1000;
[_locationManager setActivityType:CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation];
[_locationManager setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically:YES];
```

Now in the

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

I am calling a delegate to call the server api, but the problem is this delegate function didupdatelocations function is called continuously (even if I dont move) thus calling the server api. But I want to call it only when the user has moved say 100m. I am working on simulator.

I am new to this area, can anyone suggest how to do it?

Hope you understand the problem
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Even after setting desiredDistance to 100m the didupdatelocation is called continuously.

Comment: Can you show your code that sets up your locationManager and where you set the distance filter?  Also you have `setActivityType` set to Automotive.  This setting may prevent or slow the locationManager from pausing its updates.  As per docs "This activity might cause location updates to be paused only when the vehicle does not move for an extended period of time."

Comment: Have you tried removing or changing `setActivityType:CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation` ?  The AutomotiveNavigation setting can delay the pausing of the locationManager.

Comment: @rmp i want to call a rpc when the user move 100m. thats y i am using CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation

Comment: you may want to try other types to better tell the OS what your app needs the location for. iOS uses the activitType to determine when/if it can pause updates.  I would also recommend trying `allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout:` instead since you are only interested in 100m+ changes.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`distanceFilter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/distanceFilter) property of the CLLocationManager to 100 meters and you will only get events when that much movement has happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-distanceFilter` property on the CLLocationManager while instituting it.

```
locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;
```

In this way the delegate callback will be called only if the difference between the previous and the last location is over 100m.
Pay attention that 100m is a really small distance, an location coordinates can easily fluctuate over 100m.

If you want to improve that mechanism you must relate it to the CLLocation object accuracy. In the delegate callback of the manager you can elaborate each coordinate an decide if they should be sent to the server or not. For instance I would use the 100m distance filter only if the accuracy is in the range of 10 meters.

Comment: even after setting distanceFilter the - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations function is still called continuously. I have not moved I am on simulator

Comment: Did you trace the real distance between subsequent CLLocation objs? as I said the signal fluctuate around your real position so even if you don't move, you can get more locations with distances bigger than 100m